# SSH to bitbucket returing Permission Denied (publickey)

Tags: ssh, git, ubuntu-12.04, putty, public-key

So I am trying to clone a repo to a directory on my Ubuntu server but I keep getting a Permission Denied (publickey) error.

This is very weird because my output for `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` shows success:

```
mo@li515-148:/var/www$ ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
conq: logged in as msamman.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
```

However when I try to clone, I am getting an error:

```
mo@li515-148:/var/www$ sudo git clone git@bitbucket.org:username/website-development.git
Cloning into 'website-development'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

here is the verbose output:

```
mo@li515-148:/var/www$ ssh -v git@bitbucket.org
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [207.223.240.182] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/mo/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/mo/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mo/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mo/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mo/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mo/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 97:8c:1b:f2:6f:14:6b:5c:3b:ec:aa:46:46:74:7c:40
debug1: Host 'bitbucket.org' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/mo/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/mo/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Remote: Forced command: conq username:msamman
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Remote: Forced command: conq username:msamman
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to bitbucket.org ([207.223.240.182]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
conq: logged in as msamman.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to bitbucket.org closed.
Transferred: sent 3072, received 2904 bytes, in 0.2 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 14028.4, received 13261.2
debug1: Exit status 0
```

This is an Ubuntu 12.04 server and I am SSHing to it through PuTTY. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the problem.

I made ssh keys for my user account `mo`. Thats why `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` returned success.

However, calling `sudo git clone ......` uses the root account, which doesn't have ssh access to bitbucket.

I simply had to give `mo` permissions to `/var/www` folder to bypass using sudo and that fixed my problem.

Comment: Gold, suspected it was something related to sudo and root but had to search a lot to find this!

Answer (score 2):

I use:

sudo -u myuser git clone git@.....

where myuser is the user from where I´m executing and sshkey is authorized on bitbucket.